# ReactJS page transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, transition

I'm new to ReactJS so this may be a straightforward and simple thing to do, but I wanted to make page transitions like how they are in a native app. For example, in chrome (at least for android) if you swipe on the for nav-bar you can change between the pages, that kind of transition is what I'm looking for.

This is the component which will render the pages and animations between them:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Back, Answer } from './elements';
import './mobileApp.css';
import './animations.css'
import Swipe from 'react-easy-swipe';
import { Route, Link, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

const botNavStyle = {
    width: window.innerWidth/3,
    margin: 0
}

const webStyle = {
    fontSize: '1.2em',
    margin: 0,
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: 69
}

class MobileAppAnswer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            num: 0,
            lastNum: (this.props.answers).length
        }
        this.backClick = this.backClick.bind(this);
        this.nextClick = this.nextClick.bind(this);
        this.swipeNext = this.swipeNext.bind(this);
        this.swipeBack = this.swipeBack.bind(this);
    }

    backClick(){
        this.setState({num: this.state.num - 1, swipe: 'Right'});
        document.scrollingElement.scrollTo(0,0)
    }

    nextClick(){
        this.setState({num: this.state.num + 1, swipe: 'Left'});
        document.scrollingElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    swipeNext(){
        if (this.state.num < this.state.lastNum - 1){
            this.nextClick();
            this.props.history.push(`/answer${this.state.num + 1}`)
        }
    }

    swipeBack(){
        if (this.state.num > 0){
            this.backClick();
            this.props.history.push(`/answer${this.state.num - 1}`)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let websitePosition = document.getElementById('websitePosition').getBoundingClientRect();
        this.pos = {top: websitePosition.top, left: websitePosition.left};
    }

    render(){
        const back = this.state.num > 0;
        const next = this.state.num < this.state.lastNum - 1;
        return (
            <div style={{minHeight: window.innerHeight}}>
                <header className="top" style={{height: Math.round(window.innerHeight/11)}}>
                    <Back handleClick={this.props.backClick} />
                    <p style={{fontSize: '1.2em', margin: 0, visibility: 'hidden'}} id="websitePosition">{this.props.websites[0]}</p>
                </header>
                <Route render={({location}) => (
                    <TransitionGroup>
                        <CSSTransition
                            timeout={1000}
                            classNames="fade"
                            key={location.key}
                        >
                            <Switch location={location}>
                                <Route path="/answer0" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[0]}</p>
                                )} />

                                <Route path="/answer1" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[1]}</p>
                                )} />

                                <Route path="/answer2" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[2]}</p>
                                )} />

                                <Route path="/answer3" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[3]}</p>
                                )} />

                                <Route path="/answer4" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[4]}</p>
                                )} />

                                <Route path="/" render={() => (
                                    <p style={{...webStyle, ...this.pos}}>{this.props.websites[0]}</p>
                                )} />
                            </Switch>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>
                )} />
                <Swipe
                    onSwipeLeft={this.swipeNext}
                    onSwipeRight={this.swipeBack}
                    tolerance={100}
                >
                    <Route render={({location}) => (
                        <TransitionGroup>
                            <CSSTransition
                                timeout={1000}
                                classNames={"crunch"}
                                key={location.key}
                            >
                                <Switch location={location}>
                                    <Route path={'/answer0'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[0]} />
                                    )} />

                                    <Route path={'/answer1'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[1]} />
                                    )} />

                                    <Route path={'/answer2'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[2]} />
                                    )} />

                                    <Route path={'/answer3'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[3]} />
                                    )} />

                                    <Route path={'/answer4'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[4]} />
                                    )} />

                                    <Route path={'/'} render={() => (
                                        <Answer question={this.props.question} answer={this.props.answers[0]} />
                                    )} />
                                </Switch>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        </TransitionGroup>
                    )} />
                </Swipe>
                <div className="bot">
                    {back ?
                    <Link to={`answer${this.state.num-1}`}>
                        <p className="botItem button" style={{...botNavStyle, opacity: 1}} onClick={this.backClick}>{'< Back'}</p>
                    </Link>:
                    <p className="botItem button" style={{...botNavStyle, opacity: 0.5}}>{'< Back'}</p>}

                    <p className="botItem" style={botNavStyle}>Answer {this.state.num + 1}</p>

                    {next ?
                    <Link to={`answer${this.state.num+1}`}>
                        <p className="botItem button" style={{...botNavStyle, opacity: 1}} onClick={this.nextClick}>{'Next >'}</p>
                    </Link> :
                    <p className="botItem button" style={{...botNavStyle, opacity: 0.5}}>{'Next >'}</p>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MobileAppAnswer);
```

The second `Switch` which renders the `Answer` components has a basic animation which just changes the height from 0 to 100% or vice-versa. The code for the `Answer` component is:

```js
export function Answer(props){
    return (
        <div style={container}>
            <div className="info" style={infoStyle} id="question">
                <p style={{margin: 0}}>{props.question}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="info" style={infoStyle}>
                <p className="notCenter">{props.answer}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`container` and `infoStyle` are just objects which dictate some style.

The `animations.css` just has the animations required to make the `CSSTransition` work:

```css
.fade-enter, .fade-appear {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 600ms linear 400ms;
}

.fade-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 400ms linear;
}


.crunch-enter, .crunch-appear {
    height: 0%;
}

.crunch-enter-active {
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 600ms ease-out 400ms;
}

.crunch-exit {
    height: 100%;
}

.crunch-exit-active {
    height: 0%;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in
}
```

Here is the [complete code](https://github.com/NPS-Cisco-2019/Frontend), and

This is the [github.io wesbite](https://nps-cisco-2019.github.io/Frontend/)
(youll have to open the website on your phone if you want to see it)

Answer (score 0):

[react-tiger-transition](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-tiger-transition) does full page transitions.

You can try it, the docs/demo site has interactive examples.

[image: demo-gif]

*(I'm the author)